# Codeigniter cannot get data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I get following error while trying to get data from my database:

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'faq'

SELECT *FROM (`faq`, `faq`)WHERE `faq_title` = 'title 1'

Please help me to find my mistake. Here is my model:

```
public function did_get_faq_data($title){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('faq');   
    $this->db->where('faq_title', $title); 

    $query = $this->db->get('faq');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query table name is called two times. This is unnecessary.
Just replace $query = $this->db->get('faq'); to **$query = $this->db->get();**
the bold one is correct.

public function did_get_faq_data($title){

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('faq');   
$this->db->where('faq_title', $title); 

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
return $query->result();
}
else {
return false;
}
```

}